# How is this method solving my factorial?

Tags: ruby, factorial

I'm working on a ruby challenge and had to write a method that would calculate the Factorial of a number. I came across a solution below, but I don't understand how it works, specifically the section in the else statement:

```
def factorial(number)
  if number <= 1
    1
  else
    number * factorial(number - 1)
  end
end
```

Lets say I run **factorial(5)**
How is the else statement iterating through 5*4*3*2*1 in the **number * factorial(number - 1)** statement? I know this probably seems like it should be obvious, but it's not for me. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This concept is known as [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

factorial(5) evaluates to

```
5 * factorial(4)
```

factorial(4) evaluates to

```
4 * factorial(3)
```

factorial(3) evaluates to

```
3 * factorial(2)
```

factorial(2) evaluates to

```
2 * factorial(1)
```

factorial(1) evaluates to 1 because `1 <= 1`

Substituting values appropriately results in

```
5 * factorial(4)
5 * 4 * factorial(3)
5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Comment: I was just writing my understanding when I saw your answer come in. So in the else statement it's continuing to call itself through the method, -1. When it gets to 1 it stops. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. This is because the method only calls itself when the else branch is evaluated. When n = 1, there is no recursive call -- only the if branch is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `factorial` from the `else`, that's an example of [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion): calling the function you're currently in from itself.  Which sounds weird, but what you're really doing is calling a *new copy* of the function, with a new argument.  Which means that the flow starts over again from the top of the function, while remembering where to go back to when it finishes the new copy:

So you first call `factorial(5)`, which does this:

```
def factorial(5)
  if 5 <= 1
    1
  else
    5 * factorial(5 - 1)
```

Well, now before we can continue we have to call `factorial(5-1)` and use its return value to replace that expression.  Of course, Ruby does the subtraction before the call so by the time we get to the recursive call the argument is already just 4:

```
  def factorial(4)
    if 4 <= 1
      1
    else
      4 * factorial(4 - 1)
```

Whups, another recursive call.  Here we go again:

```
    def factorial(3)
      if 3 <= 1
        1
      else
        3 * factorial(3 - 1)
```

And again:

```
      def factorial(2)
        if 2 <= 1
          1
        else
          2 * factorial(2 - 1)
```

And one more time:

```
        def factorial(1)
          if 1 <= 1
            1
```

Hold your horses!  1 is in fact less than or equal to 1, so we don't hit the `else` clause this time.  We just return 1 to our caller up there in the `factorial(2)` copy - so where it had `2 * factorial(1)`, we replace `factorial(1)` with the return value, which is just 1:

```
          2 * 1
        end
      end
```

So that now returns 2 to its caller, which was the `factorial(3)` copy.  That means that `3 * factorial(2)` becomes just `3 * 2`:

```
        3 * 2
      end
    end
```

And up in the `factorial(4)` copy, `4 * factorial(3)` becomes `4 * 6`:

```
      4 * 6
    end
  end
```

And finally, back up top in our original `factorial(5)` call, that `5 * factorial(4)` becomes `5 * 24:

```
    5 * 24
  end
end
```

And that is of course the desired answer 120.